# Spring Boot can't autowire map bean in @configuration class

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, configuration, javabeans, autowired

I have created a map in my @Configuration class which holds all classes that need to be injected.
I'm trying to create a map in there that has to be injected into another class.

The Map creating looks like this in the configuration file:
[image]

This is how I inject the map:

[image]

The map is always zero so it seems like it doesn't get injected at all.

Any ideas why this might happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learned some new things while looking through stackoverflow.

Turns out spring and spring boot treat @Autowired differently and I'm supposed to use
the @Resource annotation for injecting maps in spring boot.

Besides that I was checking if the map was null inside the constructor of the class it gets injected into. When I checked it outside of the constructor the map did not seem to be null.

I guess this means the injection happens after the constructor, which I was not aware of.